# Code signing mismatch error

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I am in the process of archiving my app however I have ran into an issue.

Basically I am receiving this error:

**error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.**

I can see that the code signing is indeed mismatched however, I haven't managed to find the location of the 'Embedded Binary Signing Certificate' to fix the issue. Can someone let me know where I can change this?

Thanks.